# Tridion 2009 SP1 Publish HTML Fragment DCP to file store

Tags: tridion

In a client's SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 implementation, I'm looking to publish some DCPs as HTML fragments onto the file store. This is because a current implementation uses ASCX components on the file store and we need to replace this functionality with HTML fragments as the output.

Looking in the 2009 SP1 Content Delivery Implementation Manual, there only appear to be 4 configuration settings that can be used within the Publication -> Dcp configuration node within the cd_broker_conf.xml file.
These are:

- Jsp
- Asp
- Xml
- Txt

Is it possible to store DCP HTML fragments on the file store and if so, which config setting should be chosen?

I understand that I could just store these as .txt files, but I'd much prefer them to be .html files.

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is possible, but as you mention in your post, You will need to just use TXT as your output format. These options are design to support the 3 different ways of handling DCP content.

1. ASCX and JSP need to get resolved so any code will get executed (dynamic component links etc)
2. XML DCPs can optionally be transformed using a Dynamic Component Template in the form of an XSLT at request time
3. All other DCPs are handled as plain text as the can't contain any server side code.

Can I ask why you don't want to use the TXT type?

Comment: Cheers Chris - It's not that I don't want to use the txt type, it just makes sense that if I choose HTML Fragment in the CT, it should be added to the file store as a .html file. The above description makes perfect sense though - thanks for the description of each option. If only the documentation had the same!

Comment: Chris, I've finally had chance to check your answer and it seems that outputting the DCP as an HTML fragment is inserted in the broker database regardless of the <txt> setting in the broker config file.

I've updated the Text Component Presentation Binding to be

<Binding Name="TextComponentPresentation" Class="com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.FSTextComponentPresentationHome"/>

but still the html fragments are stored in the DB.

Using these configurations, updating the DCP to output as plain text outputs to the file store correctly.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Is it that HTML Fragments can never be stored on the file store? Will I HAVE to choose Plain Text as the output format?